# Accidentally deleted dpkg executable

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

By mistake I have deleted dpkg executable from bin folder. Now whenever I try to install anything I get the following error message:

```
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Comment: `apt-get` does not download packages to any folder called `bin` (it puts them in `/var/cache/apt/archives`) and in any case it will re-download anything that got deleted should you ask it to install the package again (using `apt-get` or `aptitude` or Synaptic). Deleting packages should not cause any harm, really. What exactly did you delete, and from where?

Comment: If you have your distribution LiveCD you can try to copy same files from it

Comment: @ Celada I deleted dpkg pakage from /usr/bin by mistake

Comment: And what distro do you have?

Comment: @user3859872 there are no packages in `/usr/bin`. Did you perchance delete `/usr/bin/dpkg`, the program?

Comment: @Costas But I dont have LiveCD right now :(

Comment: @Celada Yups exactly this got deleted. Please help me to solve this

Comment: You have to download LiveCD or try to build `dpkg` from source code by make + make install

Comment: @Costas I have downloaded the dpkg executable file but unable to copy to /usr/bin/

Comment: Do you have `root`-privileges?

Comment: Yes in my system there is only one user

Comment: Try to copy with `sudo`

Comment: Even after that when I tried to install sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
I got following error Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: The simplest thing would be to download the dpkg package from the net, using e.g. a browser. Then unpack it, and copy the missing `/usr/bin/dpkg` executable in manually, assuming that is all that is missing. Even easier `apt-get download dpkg` or `aptitude download dpkg` may work in the absence of `/usr/bin/dpkg`.

Answer (score 2):

Per clarification in comments, you accidentally deleted `/usr/bin/dpkg` (not "deleted dpkg packages").

You will have to replace that file in order to get a working system again. There are at least two approaches:

- The cleanest way is to boot a rescue system or Live CD/USB and reinstall `dpkg` on the system. If a rescue system mounts your root filesystem at `/target`, then the following command should do it:

  apt-get download dpkg
  dpkg --root=/target -i /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg*.deb
- Download a copy of the `dpkg` package appropriate for your distribution from http://packages.debian.org/ or http://packages.ubuntu.com/ or whatever is appropriate for your distribution.

  Then, extract it using these commands:

  ```
  mkdir x
  cd x
  ar x ../path/to/where/the/downloaded/file/is/dpkg_version_amd64.deb
  tar xzf data.tar.gz
  ```

  Then copy the file into place:

  ```
  cp usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin
  ```

  Now re-install a clean version of dpkg to correct whatever state might be out of sync between the package manager's idea of what's installed and what's actually installed:

  ```
  apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
  ```

Comment: Even after that when I tried to install sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
I got following error Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Most likely that was preceded by another error message which is necessary to understand the true cause.

Comment: @user3859872 Try running `dpkg --version` from the command line prompt. What does this do?

Comment: @Gilles I got the following output version 1.17.5 (amd64).